# region monitoring accuracy in iOS 5/6, late 2012

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, location, geofencing

I am trying to use region monitoring for my app, but I am trying to use it with accuracy on the order of what building in a given city area the user is in.

Reading through other articles here on region monitoring, I have gotten a bunch of conflicting arguments on the accuracy of the system. Now, at the end of 2012, what is the accuracy like?

From my own testing it seems to be checking me into locations that are a few dozen meters away from where I am, which is too granular for my needs. I need to know if this is an issue with region monitoring or just my implementation.

Thanks, and I hope this question isn't too much of a repetition of other ones, but the dates of those questions and responses makes getting the current answer confusing.